# btcchina how to deposit with mastercard?

Tags: trading, funds

https://vip.btcchina.com

I'm trying to "Fund CNY" to use in my bitcoin trades. 
The problem is, whichever bank I choose, it redirects to a login page asking for a password or mobile payment option which I don't know how to use.

I only have the mastercard payment option. How can I fund?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you need to make a wire transfer to a china bank or fund your account with bitcoins